# FileNotFoundException AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, device

I am working through my first Android app and have gotten it to work in the emulator but am unable to get it running on a real device (myTouch running cupcake).

I have put the app out on my web site accessible through a link with type attribute set to **`application/vnd.android.package-archive`** and I have also added that mime type to apache (and restarted it). I can download the app with my phone but when I try and install it I get an error message.

I have verified that the apk file actually has it, which is does.

I have signed the apk file with a personal key.

I tried the same process on the emulator (downloading via web) and had the same negative result. The log does give some additional information, basically that there is a `FileNotFoundException` while trying to load the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

I looked into installing the app via usb, but found no way to do so.

All of the documentation I have come across pretty much glosses over installing the app on your own phone, so I am thinking it is easy and I am just missing something.

Just as a last bit of info... I am developing with Eclipse 3.5 on Ubuntu and Java 6.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave a vote to "commonsware.com"'s answer as that looks like it would be helpful either way; however, after a little fiddling with it this morning I was able to install it via the web. It looks like it was an issue with the cache settings on my web server... they were keeping me from actually getting the updated content. I will have to dig deeper into this to figure out the best way to deliver apk files.

Answer (score 3):

To install the app on your own phone via USB, use `adb install path/to/apk`.

See [Android Debug Bridge (adb) > Install an app](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#move).

Comment: Thanks, I will have to try that. Is this something meant only for debugging or is it the standard way to install "your own" apps. Also, I would still rather be able to install from the web, which would then allow others to install it without having to use the market.

Comment: I am not sure what you feel the difference is between debugging and installing "your own" apps. I think your APK or device is seriously messed up, given the error message you cite. If I am correct in this assessment, you will get the same basic error with adb install as you got from your Web-based install route.

Comment: Please see my answer below. It was a caching/mimetype issue with the server, there was no issue with the apk file itself.

The difference I see is that there is the case when I am simply trying to debug an app on a real device, which makes sense to use adb, while there is another case when I have created an app that I would like to use (or give to others) without the need of putting it in the "android market", this would be the web-installation approach. (Slideme.org does this to give you their market application)